# Do any NoSQL databases support some type of row level security or label security?

Tags: nosql

I am still learning about NoSQL databases and their capabilities.  One of my concerns is being able to apply something similar to Oracle Security Labels or some type of row level security.  Do any NoSQL databases support something similar to this?  Is this even possible with document based db's or column family style databases?

Comment: There is no fundamental reason why per-document permission handling would not be possible in a document database, yet I know of no document database which has such a feature.